# Database query - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to write a database query and i've been scratching my head at what i'm doing wrong.

Here's the relevant model

```
class User

  has_one :store
  has_many :products, through: :store

  enum gender: %i[menswear womenswear unisex] 

  def menswear
    self.gender == 'menswear'
  end

  def womenswear
    self.gender == 'womenswear'
  end

end

class Product
  belongs_to :store
end
```

and controller is

```
class UsersController

  def index
    @male = User.menswear
    @female = User.womenswear
    @products = Product.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

end
```

View

```
<% @male.products.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
  <% for product in group %>
    <%= link_to product_path(product) do %>
      <%= image_tag product.secimage_url(:index).to_s, class: "image hide" %>
      <%= image_tag product.image_url(:index).to_s, class: "image" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Did the same for womenswear aswell.
But i'm getting a `NoMethodError`

`undefined method 'products' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbd25e42ac0>`

**EDIT: I might have been unclear initially, i want the view to show the products sorted by menswear and womenswear, Please help! Thanks**

Any pointers on what i'm doing wrong would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Migration

I added gender to Users later and not in the original migration

```
def up
    add_column :users, :gender, :integer
    add_index :users, :gender
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :gender
  end
```

**UPDATE:** I changed the users controller to this

```
def index
  @partners = User.partner
  @male = User.find_by(gender: 0)
  @female = User.find_by(gender: 1)
end
```

It works but only returns the first instance in both the male and female. I need it to return **all** of it!

Comment: You try to call `User#products` instance method on User relation.

Comment: So it should be User.store.products? @MarekLipka

Comment: I might be really out of touch with rails, but it looks like `menswear` is an instance method of `User`. But you are using it as a class method. Im not sure how you even managed to get to calling `products` on `@male`

Comment: Can you show me the database schema or migration file.

Comment: @Thananjaya What migration file exactly?

Comment: Like, there will be a file 20180301_create_user.rb and 20180301_create_products.rb . These files are known as migration files, which can be found in `db/migrate/migration_file`. Kindly, post it.

Comment: Updated @Thananjaya

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `has_one :through` association with `has_many :through` association here. You can check proper documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association). You are having `has_one :store` and trying to make association `has_many :products, through: :store`, which is not possible.

Either make it has_one through like:

```
has_one :store
has_one :product, through: :store
```

Or for your case make it has_many :through like:

```
has_many :stores
has_many :product, through: :stores
```

Or you can remove through from `has_many :products, through: :store` and make it `has_many :products`

Choosing solution is upto your requirement.

Comment: `undefined method 'products' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbd25e42ac0>` error while trying to retrive products from user object. Did you get problem now?

Comment: The error is because of calling `products` on `ActiveRecord_Relation`. No matter how you define associations, the error will stay as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
def index
  @partners = User.partner
  @male = User.find_by(gender: 0)
  @female = User.find_by(gender: 1)
end
```

with

```
 def index
      @partners = User.partner
      @male = User.where(gender: 0)
      @female = User.where(gender: 1)
    end
```

Comment: Returned a `undefined method 'products' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbd27f356b0>`